# Getting "Element.setCapture() is deprecated" warning on console while using on:click function of Svelte JS

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svelte

**I have a code block like this,**

```
{#if categoryArray}
  <div class="searchCategoriesBottom">
    <div class="search-form" on:keydown>
      <ul class="categoryListUl">
        {#each categoryArray as catName, index}
          <li
            class="categoryLi"
            on:focus={dispatch('click', catName)}
            on:click={openSelectedCat}
          >
            <span class="categoryDescription">{catName}</span>
          </li>
        {/each}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
{/if}
```

I want a container to be opened under it when the "li" element is clicked on mobile phones. When I tried it in Chrome, safari browser, there was no problem, but when I tried it from Firefox browser on my computer, I got this error and the subcategory does not open.

[image]

I'm just using on:click. I don't understand why this error occurs. Can anybody help me ? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue. I believe it may be a bug with Firefox; if I double click my `<button>` that has the onClick handler (note the camelcase, I'm using React), the click is fired. On any other browser, the click is fired with a single click.

Answer (score 1):

That code is injected by the dev tools to simulate touch interactions (as the name of the file in the warning indicates). You can click that file link and see the exact code used.

The click should still work, though, at least I cannot reproduce the issue. This is *not* an error.

(By the way, in general you should *only* add click handler to interactive elements that are supposed to be clicked, i.e. form elements like `button`. Otherwise the result will be not accessible.)

Comment: I also get this error, it only occurs in mozilla firefox.

Comment: @sockevalley: It's *not* an error, just a deprecation warning.

Comment: What they mean by "error" is probably "bug". This issue is only occurring on Firefox, other browsers handle the onClick event properly.

Comment: @EdwinFinch As I stated in my answer, I could not observe any actual problems. The click was handled as expected. Maybe it is an Firefox version or OS-specific problem.

Comment: What OS & FF version are you on? I'm on macOS 12.6, FF 106.0.5.

Comment: @EdwinFinch: Windows 10,  FF 106.0.5 (64-bit).

Comment: Unreal. I just came back after breakfast and ran the EXACT same code that I had on my Mac before breakfast, and magically the issue has disappeared. The button now works with a single click, without me making a single change. Consider me baffled.

Comment: Same issue Im facing with TailWindCSS 3.2.7 on macOS FireFox and also on real mobile with Chrome. The onclick event is ignored on mobile views.

Comment: Apparently this bug still exists in FF, and it results in clicks not being handled  a majority of the time. I guess I'll just stop using FF dev tools...